# Android data binding generates Cannot Resolve Method

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I'm trying to add databinding to my project according to [Android Developers Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions) and I'm getting a 'Cannot resolve method' error for `setUser`. I'm getting really frustrated and disgusted with Android programming.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >
    <data>
        <variable name="viewmodel"
            type="com.craigwashere.Wyse60.User"
            />
    </data>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

            <TextView
                android:text="@{viewmodel.name}"
                android:id="@+id/main_view"
                android:layout_width="350dip"
                android:layout_height="350dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:breakStrategy="simple"
                android:ems="80"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntumono_r"
                android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
                android:lines="42"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:typeface="monospace"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

            ...

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

User.java:

```
package com.craigwashere.Wyse60;
public class User
{
    public String name;
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public User(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    final static String TAG = "MainActivity";

    //simple Data binding to textView
    User user;
...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        user = new User("JJJJ");
        ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        binding.setUser(user);

        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I've noticed no java files are generated like the documentaion implies they should be.

I've upgraded gradle. Different layout styles either mess up the view or have no effect.

What am I missing?

EDIT: Android Studio seems to be generating files, just not reflecting them

EDIT2: Apparently, Android Studio doesn't generate any `set<class_name>` functions. It creates a `setViewmodel`, but if User class extends `ViewModel` and I use `setViewmodel`, Android Studio can't find the main package.

EDIT3: I need to clarify: The setter function Android Studio creates is based on the **variable name set in the XML file**, which I set to 'viewmodel'. Because I'm a genius.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable data binding first. Place this part in your app `build.gradle` file:

for Groovy usage

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

for Kotlin Dsl usage

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
    }
}
```

Start exploring data binding from [documentation start](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start).

Comment: I have `dataBinding { enabled = true }` in build.gradle (Module:app).

Comment: It is not a correct way to enable `dataBinding`. Pls enable `dataBinding` in a way I described above.

Answer (score 0):

As Android Studio parses the package name, whenever it finds a section that starts with a capital letter, it looks for a class. I had assumed it would take the last section as the class name. I restructured my project to mimic the Kotlin codelabs example, which generated an error that led me to this conclusion. (Something like `Could not make guess for ActivityMainBindingImpl`). Changing `com.craigwashere.Wyse60.User` to `com.craigwashere.wyse60.User` probably would have solved my issue in addition to `setViewmodel`. It's always something fundamentally trivial that causes me a few days of headache. 
 
As an FWI, if you have to change your package name, you might need to manually edit the namespace in `build.gradle`. 
 
Also, I don't know if

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

is any different than

```
android {
    ...
   dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

but I'll change it nonetheless.